# Slow screenshot upload for app1

Tags: performance, windows-phone-8, screenshot

I'm trying to upload app store listing to the WP8 platform.
So I have to upload 1 screenshot at a time and then wait for it to "save" it, which is very annoying, do you know any way to batch upload the 8 images at once?
I attached a screenshot of the upload images process below

[image: the screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an "upload all" link just above (circled red in the screenshot):

[image: DevCenter upload all]

Click on it, select all your pictures and icons, and they'll automatically be put at the right place based on their size.

Comment: man this is emberrassing haha! Well at least it was very simple to solve, thank you buddy and have an awesome new year!